# How do I add YouTube Handle (link) to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, youtube, url, youtube-channel

To be super clear when I add a new social link with @oneManDev on Facebook it automatically gets rid of the @ sign so when the user clicks on the link it redirects to https://youtube.com/oneManDev instead of https://youtube.com/@oneManDev which leads to Page not found error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to crack this. Add a "+" sign before the handle you enter in the Username field when editing the Youtube social link of your Facebook business page, e.g.:

+@utifulapp

:)

Comment: I found that the trick above from PavelAtanassov about adding a "+" sign before the @handlename also worked for me, i.e., like so "+@handlename".

Comment: Thanks @PavelAtanassov 
And if it's like in my case: not saving changes in Safari, use Chrome.
For Linkedin, just omit the "in/" 

I wish I wish that Facebook would just disappear into thin air

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to add your youtube URL to my profile, and it worked fine.  I was using a browser on my laptop, so maybe the issue is if you tried to do it using the phone app maybe?

Comment: No I used the web version of Facebook. Custom URLs work fine but newer YouTube handles don't seem to work on Facebook. Since Facebook redirects you to youtube.com/channelUrl which should be youtube.com/@channelUrl youtube just made it so you can't get Custom URLs anymore unfortuantely.

Answer (score 0):

The + sign worked for me, but only when editing from a mobile device. It doesn't work from a PC browser for some reason.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155131)

Comment: This should have been a comment on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168365/136642

Answer (score -1):

That is not functioning for me on PC, so IDK what or how to get this to work, I want to link my facebook with my youtube so I can upload to YouTube and it asks to send it to FB but they are not linked and it wont go, none of the google searches have turned up anything.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155005)